# WPF. Image. Не отображает картинку

Tags: wpf, изображения

Есть картинка `<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/bin/debug/NOAVATAR.jpg">`
В конструкторе окна оно ее видит и отображает, при запуске программы - нет. Если инициализировать ее в конструкторе класса - пишет не удается найти ресурс, но как это, если в окне она ЕСТЬ!!!??? Помогите плиз!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Исходя из `/bin/debug/`, думаю, вы делаете что-то не то.

Для начала, картинку нужно добавить в проект:

[image: картинка]

Убедитесь, что в качестве Build Action указано Resource, и отключено копирование в выходной каталог:

[image: и ещё одна]

Теперь картинку можно подключать через путь внутри проекта:

```
<Image Source="pack://application:,,,/Resources/bg.png"/>
```

Обратите внимание, что в проекте картинка лежит в каталоге `Resources`, и это соответствует пути в pack URI.

Comment: спасибо! помогло

Comment: @Awesome7997: Пожалуйста!

Comment: @VladD Сделал все по вашему ответу и все равно не помогло. Причем в конструкторе изображение отображается верно а вот после сборки exe изображение пропадает! Второй день не могу понять что происходит.

Comment: @Сергей: Ну, сложно сказать, что не так. Вопрос в том, какой у вас путь к файлу в проекте, и какой pack URI.

Comment: @VladD разобрался. В одним символе ошибся только. Плюсую ваш ответ!

Comment: @Сергей: Ага, ну вот и отлично.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего нужно открыть проект, в котором лежит картинка, и удалить приведенный на фото блок кодаЮ а дальше сделать все в соответствии с тем как написал @VladD (если еще не сделали).

[image: Порядок действий]